# Internet ham QSO website?

Tags: internet

A ham I know who is antenna-challenged logs onto an Internet site where he has QSOs with other licensed hams worldwide via his computer's microphone and speakers.

He says "it's just like being on HF", and he loves it! But I'll be darned if I can remember what it is. **It's not Echolink, not digital, and no RF is used**. Anyone know the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service I have heard of that simulates HF communications is [HamSphere](http://www.hamsphere.com/) [[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HamSphere)]. It is a paid service.

I think there might be another similar site but that's all I remember.

Comment: That's it! I searched some old emails from him for that term. Sadly, his mind is going.

Comment: From his email: "I have just started on Hamsphere 4 and having a great time. It is really very realistic. And so much simpler, or at least less hassle, than the real radio."

Comment: Some people just like to live in virtual reality :)

Comment: @PedjaYT9TP Well, I'd just like to have someone to talk to during the day. My antennas currently limit me to 75m, and and there's no one on then.

Comment: I just asked a question about this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46258094#46258094). If anyone has ever used it, kindly post your experience with Hamsphere there.

Comment: Someone on 75m last night told me that [CQ100](https://qsonet.com/programs.html) predated Hamsphere 4, and it's less expensive. Experiences?

Answer (score -1):

ECHOLINK may be the internet service being used.